# Timed out after 60 seconds waiting for element to be clickable-selenium webdriver

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Currently working on selenium web driver. am trying to find the element visualizationId but am getting the above error. 
    Here the code where am getting the error:

```
Actions actions1 = new Actions(driver);
WebElement dBox1= ((new WebDriverWait(driver,60)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("visualizationId"))));
selectByVisibleText("week");
actions1.moveToElement(dBox1);
actions1.click();
actions1.perform();
```

Here is the html tag for the above code:

```
<select id="visualizationId" style="width: 120px; display: none;" name="visualization">
<option value="day">Day</option>
<option value="week">Week</option>
<option selected="" value="month">Month</option>
```

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) says

> An expectation for checking an element is visible and enabled such that you can click it.

Since your element isn't visible (`display: none;`), it can't be clicked.

Comment: @Stijin is there any other way to find element or what changes is needed to find the element by id.

Comment: @user2994827 `driver.findElement(By.id("elementId"));`

Comment: i used those code also.. let me give solution for the hidden element or how can i make it visible with the code.

Comment: If that line doesn't work, it's by design. You're not supposed to (and you probably can't) make an element visible with WebDriver. It tries to give you what the user gets, because in the end you're testing from a user's point of view.

Comment: Is there any possibility with selenium RC

Comment: @user2994827 I doubt it but I'm not sure. You can ask a new question for that, after you've done some research of course.